# Change collision action

Tags: collision-detection, cocos2d-iphone

I have a collision detection and its working fine, the problem is, that whenever my "`bird`" is hitting a "`cloud`", the cloud dissapers and i get some points. The same happens for the "`sol`" which it should, but not with the clouds.

How can this be changed ? ive tryed a lot, but can seem to figger it out.

**Collision Code**

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt {
    bird.position = ccpAdd(bird.position, skyVelocity);

    NSMutableArray *projectilesToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (CCSprite *bird in _projectiles) {
        bird.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0);  
        CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake(bird.position.x, bird.position.y, [bird boundingBox].size.width, [bird boundingBox].size.height);

        NSMutableArray *targetsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (CCSprite *cloudSprite in _targets) {
            cloudSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0); 
            CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake(cloudSprite.position.x, cloudSprite.position.y, [cloudSprite boundingBox].size.width, [cloudSprite boundingBox].size.height);


            if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bird boundingBox], [cloudSprite boundingBox])) {
                [targetsToDelete addObject:cloudSprite];

            }                       
        }

        for (CCSprite *solSprite in _targets) {
            solSprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0); 
            CGRect absoluteBox = CGRectMake(solSprite.position.x, solSprite.position.y, [solSprite boundingBox].size.width, [solSprite boundingBox].size.height);


            if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bird boundingBox], [solSprite boundingBox])) {
                [targetsToDelete addObject:solSprite];      
                score += 50/2;
                [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score]];
            }                       
        }



        // NÅR SKYEN BLIVER RAMT AF FUGLEN
        for (CCSprite *cloudSprite in targetsToDelete) {
            //[_targets removeObject:cloudSprite];
            //[self removeChild:cloudSprite cleanup:YES];       
        }

        // NÅR SOLEN BLIVER RAMT AF FUGLEN
        for (CCSprite *solSprite in targetsToDelete) {
            [_targets removeObject:solSprite];
            [self removeChild:solSprite cleanup:YES];   


        }

        if (targetsToDelete.count > 0) {
            [projectilesToDelete addObject:bird];
        }
        [targetsToDelete release];
    }

    // NÅR FUGLEN BLIVER RAMT AF ALT ANDET
    for (CCSprite *bird in projectilesToDelete) {
        //[_projectiles removeObject:bird];
        //[self removeChild:bird cleanup:YES];
    }
    [projectilesToDelete release];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep your objects in the same list (_targets). Therefore the game can not decide if you are talking about a cloud or about a sol, both are just CCSprites for the game.
Therefore it loops through every element, handling it as a cloud and then does the same thing again, handling the objects a sol.

To prevent this save the objects into 2 differnt lists: Clouds into _cloudTargets and the sol into _solTargets and change the two loops to:

```
for (CCSprite *cloudSprite in _cloudTargets) {
      [..]   

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bird boundingBox], [cloudSprite boundingBox])) {
            [targetsToDelete addObject:cloudSprite];

        }                       
    }

    for (CCSprite *solSprite in _solTargets) {
       [..]    

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect([bird boundingBox], [solSprite boundingBox])) {
            [targetsToDelete addObject:solSprite];      
            score += 50/2;
            [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score]];
        }                       
    }
```

This should work fine.

Hope this helps

floAr